# Why is assigning a value to a pointer after realloc not working with MVC++

Tags: c, visual-c++, realloc

I am experimenting with dynamic memory allocation in C, the code doesn't work when I compile with MSVC++.

When I run the code after compiling with MSVC++, values that must be assigned to the new allocated address are not assigned and existing values pointed to are deleted. I have also noticed a lag when I run the program.

```
*(p_word+i) = word[i];
```

I have compiled and run the program with GCC (running on [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)) and it works fine. When I comment out the assignment part *(`*(p_word+i) = word[i];`)* the code run fine on both compilers.

The code also runs fine with smaller sizes string value *(Please see code comments)*

Please have a look at my code bellow, please advise if I am doing something wrong

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void main(){

    // char word[] = "Food";                    // Works fine for short string
    char word[] = "Food for the soul";
    size_t space = 1;   
    char *p_word = (char*)calloc(space, sizeof(char));

    *p_word = word[0];
    *(p_word+1) = word[1];


    for(int i = 2; i < sizeof(word)/sizeof(char); i++){     // Skip the first item

        space++;

        p_word = (char*)realloc(p_word, space * sizeof(char));

        // There's a lag
        if(p_word != NULL)
            *(p_word+i) = word[i];


    }


    // Output the data
    printf("\n %-16s| %-16s| %-16s\n", "Initial", "Current", "Contents");
    printf("-----------------+-----------------+-----------------\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(word)/sizeof(char); i++)
        printf(" %-16p| %-16p| %-16c\n", p_word, p_word+i, *(p_word+i));


    free(p_word);
    p_word = NULL;

}
```

Comment: The program has undefined behavior.

Comment: The problem is that the line `*(p_word+1) = word[1];` is trying to access the ***second*** element of the buffer pointed to by `p_word` ***but*** the line `char *p_word = (char*)calloc(space, sizeof(char));` allocates space for ***only one*** element. (And there is a similar, off-by-one, error each time the loop runs!) Changing `size_t space = 1;` to `size_t space = 2;` should fix things.

Comment: Thanx @AdrianMole, that solved it

Comment: OT: `main()`  is defined to return an `int`.

Comment: @phuclv No! The `p_word` buffer is to copy a `char[]` array, not a list of `char *` pointers.

Comment: @AdrianMole sorry I misread that